# How to request data from an open source website such as Reddit or Github and display on the Local Django Website?

Tags: django

I am quite a newbie to Django and I am trying to understand how API calls and requests work in Django. I have a simple Django website that has User login and authentication system. I want a user to save the top ten reddit posts and display them on their respective login system. I have seen the request method in Python and some web-crawling methods. I am unable to figure out a way to request data from Reddit . 
Here is the code I have written so far : 
https://github.com/darthvedder17/Django-Website-Reddit

Comment: like many big open source sites they will provide api for you to query, maybe read over reddit api to see what they provide https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/